# Why does bash sometimes show an underlined u?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sometimes, when I am typing really fast in bash, I accidentally do something and I get an underlined u diplayed at the prompt. After that, bash behaves strangely (I'm sorry, I can't remember what it does). I can never figure out what I pressed to enable the behavior. Usually I just have to resort to mashing keys to exit this mode. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like you pressed `Ctrl-Shift-u`. This will show an underlined `u` indicating you can enter a hex code of a unicode character. It is not a bash specific feature, as it works in quite some apps.

Comment: This is actually not a bash feature but a feature in the window manager/application's libraries like GTK+.

Comment: I assumed as much; but I would also think it strange if it were implemented in the wm. I think GTK is indeed the most likely candidate.